# Adapting AlertDialog to a specific design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I need to edit default AlertDialog theme so that it will look like part of the design of my app. I don't want to create a whole new theme for it. I will just play with its own properties and make small changes. But the problem is I can't manage to reach the source code and I don't know what kind of attributes it has.

What I need to do is basically to give background a little transparency and roundness.

Does anyone know where can I get the AlertDialog style code? And which attributes do I need to edit for transparency and roundness of background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the style code for AlertDialog: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

I don't know how to change it the way you want though.

Comment: Thanks. That might be the code I need to review. I haven't figured it out also